# What's the proposed way to switch to native Homebrew on M1 MacBooks?

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1, rosetta-2

I've used Homebrew via Rosetta the last couple of months. And now since the native version was released I'm not sure what the required steps are to switch.

Should I just update Homebrew and will the packages be updated automatically? Or do we have to reinstall them?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

You can install both Homebrew for Apple M1 and Homebrew for Intel.

**To install Homebrew for Apple M1**

Open a terminal that is not using Rosetta 2. For this, right click on the Terminal application and verify that "open with rosetta" is disabled. Run:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

**To install Homebrew for Intel**

Open a terminal with "open with rosetta" enabled and run:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Then you can add an alias in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
alias ibrew='arch -x86_64 /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew'
```

To install a formula xyz on Apple M1 run:

```
brew install xyz
```

If for some reasons, it doesn't work on Apple M1, you can then install the Intel version with:

```
ibrew install xyz
```

Thanks to Dominik Stötter for its original article: [TIP | The BEST way to install Homebrew (Brew) on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://wnderlvst.com/stories/5101f1ca-a1c8-4dfc-b469-ccf4dae0d823)